# Im using mobx 5.15.7 seeing weird behavior

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Hello I am use to mobx 4 just getting to mobx 5 and I noticed that the syntax and someways you read observable variables have changed I am trying to log to the console.log the output of some data Im getting from a route, but I am seeing a Proxy and some other stuff. Screenshots are posted below and an explanation would be be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have some far code wise.

```
    const { team } = this.props.teamStore;
    console.log(this.props.teamStore)
    const userTeams = !!team ? team : null;
    console.log(userTeams)
    return (
      <div className="text-center mt-40">
        <div>Home page again lets get it.</div>
        {this.getTeams()}
      </div>
    );
```

Here is the weird output I was experincing

```
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(3)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, MobX 5 uses `Proxy` under the the hood (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), and this is what it does to your observable data.

You can try to use `toJS` method on your data if you want regular console output, like that:

```
import { toJS } from 'mobx';

// ...

console.log(toJS(userTeams))
```

More here: https://www.mobxjs.com/refguide/tojson.html